# I need to replace characters in an array using ONLY a loop. I can't do anything more advanced than that. What should I do?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, character

I'm working on a faux DNA strand analyzer, and I need to create the complement strand to this one:

```
char [] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
```

Note: These are 20 characters, if that helps.

I can't hardcode this, and I need to use a loop to iterate through each character and find out how to swap the A's with T's (and vice versa) and the G's with C's (and vice versa.)

Comment: You should write some code. Did you try anything?

Comment: By the way, I realize that other questions were answered like this, but I need a more specific answer.

Comment: I'm guessing you need computer script, not pencil eraser...., What language would you like me to show you?

Comment: @EJoshuaS No, because I don't even know where to begin. Should I make an array of complements?

Comment: @Alex you can't do it *only* with a loop. At the very least, you need something to map the letters to their complement.

Comment: Hang on -- I have an idea. Let me try something real quick.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to swap all `A` for `T` and all `G` for `C` (vice-versa)?

Comment: @TwiN Yes, I need to do that.

Comment: @JimVanPetten Java would be ideal, unless I'm missing something completely here.

Comment: @alex, yeh, sorry, i didnt see the tag (my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
char[] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
char[] newTestStrand = new char[testStrand.length];
for (int i = 0, l = testStrand.length; i < l; i++)
{
   if (testStrand[i] == 'A')
   {
      newTestStrand[i] = 'T';
   }
   else if (testStrand[i] == 'T')
   {
      newTestStrand[i] = 'A';
   }
   else if (testStrand[i] == 'C')
   {
      newTestStrand[i] = 'G';
   }
   else if (testStrand[i] == 'G')
   {
      newTestStrand[i] = 'C';
   }
   else
   {
      newTestStrand[i] = testStrand[i];
   }
}
```

or with switch statement (not sure if you're allowed to use that):

```
char[] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
char[] newTestStrand = new char[testStrand.length];
for (int i = 0, l = testStrand.length; i < l; i++)
{
   switch (testStrand[i])
   {
      case 'A':
        newTestStrand[i] = 'T';
        break;
      case 'T':
        newTestStrand[i] = 'A';
        break;
      case 'G':
        newTestStrand[i] = 'C';
        break;
      case 'C':
        newTestStrand[i] = 'G';
        break;
      default:
        newTestStrand[i] = testStrand[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

But in reality I'd recommend representing the swaps somehow (key value pairs) and looping through the potential swaps. I stuck to the simple solution since you said "loops only"

Comment: Thank you! This is within what we've learned so far, and it is EXACTLY what I needed. One last question: how might I put these in a new array without hardcoding it all? Should I just put them in as testStrand[x], where x is whatever number I need?

Comment: Wait, no, forget that. How can I make the new array? I just realized what I said was stupid, and wouldn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer above to do just that. You'll notice I declared a new array of the same length (line 2). Then I set each element of the new array to the same element of the old array (unless it needed to be replaced).

Comment: ...or switch statements are cleaner

Comment: Agreed that switch statements are much cleaner, but I thought maybe that would surpass the "for loop only" requirement :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far. I'm now getting this error:

Comment: exit status 1
Main.java:92: error: ']' expected
    char [] compStrand[i] = testStrand[i];
                       ^
Main.java:92: error: illegal start of expression
    char [] compStrand[i] = testStrand[i];
                        ^
2 errors

Comment: (compStrand is what I was told to call the new strand.)

Comment: I'd have to see full code to understand what is going on. Did you add a char[] somewhere other than the initial declaration of the array (my line 2)?

Comment: Just fixed it, and I'm ready to go. Thank you so, so, so much, Morcous. This has been immensely helpful. And thanks for helping me with debugging it too! Again, thanks!

Comment: Funny Andy pointed out to to test my code in a compiler and the compiler pointed out issues comparing chars with strings and errors attempting to insert strings into char array...yes/no???

Answer (score 0):

Since somebody already suggested the else/if approach, here's the same but with ternary operators instead:

```
char[] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
for (int i = 0; i < testStrand.length; i++) {
    testStrand[i] = testStrand[i] == 'A' ? 'T' :
        testStrand[i] == 'T' ? 'A' :
            testStrand[i] == 'G' ? 'C' :
                testStrand[i] == 'C' ? 'G' : testStrand[i];
}
```

### Update

I noticed you asked how to insert the new values in a different array:

```
char[] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
char[] reversed = new char[testStrand.length];

for (int i = 0; i < testStrand.length; i++) {
    if (testStrand[i] == 'A') {
        reversed[i] = 'T';
    } else if (testStrand[i] == 'T') {
        reversed[i] = 'A';
    } else if (testStrand[i] == 'C') {
        reversed[i] = 'G';
    } else if (testStrand[i] == 'G') {
        reversed[i] = 'C';
    } else {
        reversed[i] = testStrand[i];
    }
}
```

### Update 2

But hey, if you're feeling wild:

```
Character[] testStrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(testStrand);
chars.replaceAll(c -> {
    switch (c) {
        case 'A': return 'T';
        case 'T': return 'A';
        case 'C': return 'G';
        case 'G': return 'C';
        default: return c;
    }
});

// print them out
chars.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: always love ternary, but maybe too advanced for this cat

Comment: yeh, i guess we should always try to give good examples of best-practice code.  Anyone want to throw out a try-catch-finally?

Comment: Compiled mine below and it gives the correct answer

Answer (score -1):

Jimmyv code:
Better?

```
char[] complementstrand = {'A', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'G', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'T'};
    for (int i = 0; i < complementstrand.length; i++) {

    if (Character.toString(complementstrand[i]).equals("A")){
complementstrand[i] = "T".charAt(0);
}

    else if (Character.toString(complementstrand[i]).equals("T")){
complementstrand[i] = "A".charAt(0);
}


    else if (Character.toString(complementstrand[i]).equals("G")){
complementstrand[i] = "C".charAt(0);
}


    else if (Character.toString(complementstrand[i]).equals("C")){
complementstrand[i] = "G".charAt(0);
}


}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(complementstrand));
```

Comment: If OP is struggling to do this, giving code full of compiler and logical errors isn't a good answer.

Comment: well, i dont have eclipse here on assignment.  What do you see is wrong?  I purposely avoided the elseif since there were suggestions to be minimal as possible...

Comment: If you've got internet access, [you've got a Java compiler](https://ideone.com/bk7eBf).

Comment: Thank you Andy!  The devil is in the details eh?